# How to force https to any http page request on an Apache 2.4 server

Tags: apache-2.4, https, http

I saw a solution to this at [HTTP to HTTPS redirect not working on Apache 2.4](https://serverfault.com/questions/868625/http-to-https-redirect-not-working-on-apache-2-4)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

My question is, doesn't this directive send any and all page requests on a site to `https://www.example.com/`?

How do you get `http://www.example.com/someDir/somePage.html` to resolve to `https://www.example.com/someDir/somePage.html` using Apache 2.4 directives?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) states:

> Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.

So you don't do anything else.